# How can I install the vanilla Gingerbread launcher?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, launcher

Is there any way for me to install Gingerbread's vanilla launcher application? So far, I prefer the "stock" Sony Ericsson launcher but I do want to know what the actual Gingerbread launcher is like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [several versions uploaded to the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=gingerbread%20launcher&c=apps). I cannot personally attest to the safety or nature of them, but they generally all claim to be "pulled from the SDK" or similar.

One exception is that I do recall trying the one named "[Android 2.3 Launcher (Home)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moo.android.launcher.gingerbread&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tb28uYW5kcm9pZC5sYXVuY2hlci5naW5nZXJicmVhZCJd)" briefly in the past and it worked fine and wasn't doing anything shady (it's review average is ~4.2 stars at the moment).